# Python Scheduling jobs with schedule along with socket module not working

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, sockets, scheduler

I am trying to create a sockets server (TCP/IP) and inside it based on few data from client I am scheduling few background jobs.

following code is working ->

```
import schedule
import time

def test1():
    print('hi from 1')
 
def test2():
    print('hi from test2')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then I tried following thing with socket server then its not executing the jobs/function. Can someone help me what's happening here.

Not working code

```
import schedule
import time
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 8009)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

def test1():
    print('hi from 1')
 
def test2():
    print('hi from test2')
 
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(test1)
schedule.every(2).minutes.do(test2)
 
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
 
    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    
    data = connection.recv(1024)
    result =  data.decode('utf-8')
    print('data recived from clinet : ', result)
```

Thing I am trying to achieve is I want to create python socket server which
will accept request from node client's and based on clients data I want to schedule few jobs in python. for this I am using socket, schedule moduls from python to create socket server and schedule jobs respective and net module at node js's client for sending data to python server.

Answer (score 1):

Please explain your problem in more detail. sock.accept is blocking, so the loop is blocking, is this your problem?

To prevent the program from blocking you can run the scheduler loop in a separate thread and the acceptance loop also in a separate thread too. Create a main thread to manage your child threads. Have a look at the module [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Maybe it makes sense to use an other [scheduler library](https://gitlab.com/DigonIO/scheduler) that can handle threading, see [here](https://digon.io/hyd/project/scheduler/t/master/pages/examples/threading.html).

*Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of the scheduler library*

Comment: I am able t solved the problem by getting better understanding of thread and schedule module.